# Statsmodels- How to model a multivariate SARIMAX with linear lag-regression order higher than 1

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels

I am modelling the correlation between two seasonal time series using a SARIMAX coupled model (statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX). The endogenous variable is y(t) and the exogenous variable is x(t). My objective is to forecast y(t) using x(t) as a predictor.

My understanding about the SARIMAX(p,d,q,**r**)∙(P,D,Q)s process is to model y(t) as a linear function of x(t) with error terms that follow a SARIMA process:
y(t)=c+β1∙x(1,t)+β2∙x(2,t)+⋯+βr∙x(r,t)+ε(t) (See complete equation in the link
[SARIMAX model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtmRU.png)

For the aforementioned problem I have 2 questions: (1) Is it possible to model a lag regression order "**r**" higher than 1?
(2) Once estimated the SARIMAX model equation, which is the best way to forecast future values of y(t) as a function of x(t) considering x(t) is a known variable in the future? I've seen many examples for uni-variate SARIMA forecasting but not for multi-variate SARIMAX forecasting.
Many thanks.